# PHP header() only refreshing on relative file path

Tags: php

I ran into a curious situation where my page would not refresh properly upon submitting a form.

Form (`page.php`):

```
<form action="funcs/foo.php" method="post">
    <!-- various inputs -->
    <input type="submit" value="Post it">
</form>
```

And the function (`foo.php`):

```
// statements updating database, changing page layout...
header("Location:$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/page.php");
```

By changing the header to the following, page.php is refreshed.

```
header("Location:../page.php");
```

My question is *why?* What's the difference between specifying the full path and the relative path?

Comment: In this case we should use relative path.

Comment: Yuo can use like below:-

Comment: $arrConfig['siteRootURL'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/project folder/';define('SITE_ROOT_URL', $arrConfig['siteRootURL']); and then use SITE_ROOT_URL in place of $_SERVER variable

Comment: Tell me if this does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> header("Location:$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/page.php");

First, you reference array index wrong (it should be quoted:  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`) but aside from this you use it wrong as `Location` never operates on paths in context of your local filesystem as you incorrectly assume. So if you want to use relative, i.e. `/foo` it does NOT mean this is `foo` folder in root of your filesystem, but it is `foo` relative to `document root`. So passing `DOCUMENT_ROOT` gives you wrong path, unreachable for the browser.

Comment: While enclosed in double quotes, there's no need to put single quotes around `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Other than that, you are spot on. I don't know what I was thinking using DOCUMENT_ROOT in this case. Thanks!